# Add access token to every request header in Angular js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, access-token

I am working with a node js rest api. In the authentication process api returns an access token. I need to add the access token to every request from an common place.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23244809/angular-js-set-token-on-header-default

Comment: Take a look into angular js interceptors, this will satisfy your requirements. Using interceptors you can `intercept` the request `before` sending it to the server and same `after` the response is returned

Comment: thanks for the quick response. yes this is what I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`http interceptor`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)
Code looks like as follow

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, $cookies) {
  return {
   'request': function(config) {
        config.headers['Token'] = $cookies.loginTokenCookie;
        return config;
    }
  };
});
```

[From this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23244809/angular-js-set-token-on-header-default)