# AngularJS : Implementing token in $http

Tags: angularjs

I am very new to angularJS.

My Backend is DRF and I have successfully implemented token.

this is my token:

```
{
    "key": "217c3b5913b583a0dc3285e3521c58b4d7d88ce2"
}
```

Before I implement token in backend, it was working nice:

```
$scope.getAllContact = function() {
    var data = $http.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/contact")
    .then(function(response) {
      $scope.contacts = response.data;
    });
  };
```

But, now I am not getting how can I implement this token here

Can anyone help me in this case?

Comment: Try setting the token in the headers? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#setting-http-headers

Comment: Yes, i notice this before but i am not getting how to implement token header

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this. You need to attach the token in the headers.

```
$http({
   url : "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/contact",
   method : 'GET',
  headers : {
      'Content-Type' : 'application/json',    
      'key': "217c3b5913b583a0dc3285e3521c58b4d7d88ce2"
  }
}).then(function(response){
    $scope.contacts = response.data;
});
```

Note that, this is binding the token to only this request. Use `$http` interceptors to add the token to each request that you make.
See here: [Angular Js - set token on header default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23244809/angular-js-set-token-on-header-default)

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: Check if the token is getting sent in "Network" tab of Developer's tools.

Comment: I am trying to solve it now another way like when a user login, it will generate a login and it will come with token in the GET method